# Logcat for multiple devices running at the same time in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-windowmanager

As title says, I'd like to have two windows inside Android studio to see log for 2 devices running at the same time, how to achieve this? At the moment i have to switch devices all the time, but its not very handy when you have to compare different values.

I found this thread, but it's not working in AS:

[How do I get Logcat for multiple devices running at the same time in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162450/how-do-i-get-logcat-for-multiple-devices-running-at-the-same-time-in-eclipse)

Comment: If you're using the Android Device Monitor, it shows all the devices detected by the adb in the left panel. You can choose which device to show the logcat output from using the dropdown.

Comment: I am using that right now, i want to see both devices at the same time..

Comment: You cannot see both devices at the same time inside the Android Device Monitor. You might want to use the two console windows as provided in the link you mentioned.

Comment: Ahh pretty clumsy solution, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular "Android" view for one device, then run your app on the other device in debug mode. In the debug view, you can view the logcat output in the Logcat tab there. Then make both the Android and Debug views floating to see them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Open two Android Studio projects, open the Android Monitor on both windows and you can alternatively choose one device in each one.