# Debug on many phones in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Is it possible to debug an app on many phones at the same time in Android Studio? By this I mean launching multiple debug instances, each one on a different phone, like in Eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775675/logcat-for-multiple-devices-running-at-the-same-time-in-android-studio)

Comment: It's not quite the same. I'm referring specifically to debugging, by which I mean running the code step by step on both phones (or more). Also, the question you mentioned has a vague answer that doesn't work in my scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of posting this question probably the only solution was the one posted by George V.M. Now, after several updates of Android Studio, this can be easily done by creating N copies of the same Debug configuration and launching each of them on a separate phone.

Comment: Very easy! Just copied the debug configuration.. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Perfect Thanks , It's not so easy to guess this is possible !

Comment: What do you mean by the same debug configuration, the copy of the whole project in a new window and run it to another physical device??

Comment: No. In the Run/Debug configurations menu just create multiple debug configurations, one for each device.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

You might want to take a look at Vlad's answer. This one is pointless for newer versions of Android Studio. In case anyone is still curious, this was my really hacky way of solving the problem

---

In case anyone out there is still looking for a solution to this, here's what I've found.

I'm working on a project that requires wireless communication between 2 instances of the same app running on 2 phones (actually, 2 or more). There were a lot of times where I wished I could debug 2 devices at a time. It wasn't until recently that I figured out how to do it.

It's actually quite simple: Have 2 instances of Android Studio open and you can debug multiple devices at once, (one device on each Android Studio instance) with breakpoints and everything!

### **Catch 1: You can't open two instances of the same project**

I haven't been able to run two instances of Android Studio where both instances have the same project open. It will just redirect you to the already open project.

**Solution:**
The solution to this is to just make a copy of your project somewhere on your PC and open that project allowing you to have two copies of the same project open.

### **Catch 2: Changes have to be made on each copy manually.**

Now here's a new problem. What if while debugging, you find a mistake in your code and amend it. Now you have to make sure you make that exact same amendment in your second copy of the project so that the second device doesn't have the same error if it hits those lines. This is annoying, having to remember to make a change twice; once in each copy of the project.

**Solution:**
My solution to this problem was to just make a 'symbolic link' of the project instead of a physical copy.

> (*A symbolic link is a 'nickname' or a 'reference' to a file. If you make a symbolic link fileB that points to fileA, although they seem like two distinct files to the OS, they in fact point to the exact same physical file. Any changes made on fileA will be reflected in fileB since they point to the same physical file/data on the disk. Instructions on how to create symbolic links are given below*)

**Now hold on just one second!!!** Making a symbolic link of the entire project might not be a very smart idea since you'll have two Android Studios trying to edit the same files. This could lead to problems, especially in the case of build files and IDE files.

So what I did was make a symbolic link of *only the source files*, or any file which I'd be editing directly and which AS wouldn't normally touch, and make a physical copy of every other file.

The only thing you need to do is remember to hit `Ctrl+S` after making changes to your code in one AS instance so that the changes will be reflected on the second one. It might still take a couple of seconds for those changes to be reflected in the second instance but you can just click the "Synchronize" button (top left, next to "Open" and "Save") on your second AS which will cause all *externally changed files*, i.e., the file you just edited in your first instance, to be reloaded from disk.

**You still need to be careful though.** Every time you make a change in one AS, make sure you save all those changes and that those changes are reflected in the second AS before you try doing any editing in the second AS. Otherwise conflicts could cause you to lose the changes you made in one copy. One way around this is to force yourself to make changes to a file only on one AS and not the other.

### Actual Instructions:

Okay that was a lot of talk. Here are the steps you can follow along with tips:

1. Close Android Studio and make a copy of your project into another folder on your PC
2. Go to your second copy and delete all your source code files since we're going to make symbolic links of them.
   (these are the files I usually make symbolic links of instead of a copy:

   - all build.gradle files
   - the entire app/src folder
   - if you have any other loose source or resource files or othwerwise non IDE files that you might edit, make symbolic links of them as well
3. Make a symbolic link of all those non IDE files from the first project folder into your second project folder.

   - to make a symbolic link of a **file** in **Windows**, use

     > `mklink path\to\symbolic\link path\to\original\file`
   - to make symbolic link of a **folder** in **Windows**, use

     > `mklink /j "path\to\symbolic\link" "path\to\original\folder"`
   - to make a symbolic link of a **file** or **folder** in **Linux**, use

     > `ln -s "path/to/original/file_or_folder" "path/to/link"`
4. Open up Android Studio again. It will probably open the original copy of your project if that was the last project you opened in AS.
5. Go to File>Open and open up the second project copy on your PC.

You will now have 2 copies of your project running and you will be able to debug your app on 2 devices at the same time! (Remember that breakpoints won't be shared between the two copies)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about attaching the debugger to several phones, I'm going to say no.
The port will be blocked with that traffic from one phone.

Unless someone figure out a hacky way to do this, atm It's not possible as far as my knowledge.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of...going back to Eclipse :-(

Comment: Could you even do this in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, you can launch the same debug configuration many times and choose a different phone for each instance.

Answer (score -1):

Android studio has its VM devices, but it requires installing Intel Accelerator because it's too slow until it show up. alternatively, I recommended "Genymotion" for running multiple instances and different devices. I'm using it and its working perfectly.

It may takes a while for setup and installing but once its installed it will be light weight and I promise you'll be pleased while working on it =)

Here is the link:
[genymotion intallation user guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide), 
[genymotion website](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

Comment: I'm interested to debug the app on many physical devices (phones) at the same time. I need this because my app uses WifiDirect and I need at least 2 phones that connect over WifiDirect for testing.