# How can I split the LogCat for 2 devices on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I know the question has already been answered here before: [How do I get Logcat for multiple devices running at the same time in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162450/how-do-i-get-logcat-for-multiple-devices-running-at-the-same-time-in-eclipse)

but "Simply click on a device to switch to its logcat." doesnt work for me.

It's really frustrating that I have to debug my debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14162450/3879470). If simply clicking on a device to switch its logcat dosen't work for you. Then try another way to get logcat. 
Try to use Logcat filters based on your process id (ie, pid) for your apps. Even for the same app on different devices its highly unlikely that pids would be same. When an App runs simply create two filters with its pids for both the devices.

Comment: The thing is that logcat doesnt log everything, sometimes it logs one device, sometimes it logs the other, sometimes it doesnt log anything at all. I was asking this question about "splitting" because I thought my eclipse or logcat is just confused because there are multiple devices running.